# how to convert images on upload without a second call to convert

Tags: filepicker.io

I am trying to figure out how to convert something on upload. Is there a "save as" option to be passed by so i can set "png" as the only format to be saved on the other side? The user still can use all image formats but i dont have to make the second step to convert everything to the right format and size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer i got via email support.

> Hi there - happy to help. The best way to do this is to "chain" the
>   .pick() and .convert() calls, like so:
>
> filepicker.pick(function(fpfile){  filepicker.convert(fpfile, {...},
>   function(stored_fpfile) {   ...  } }
>
> This way the conversion can be done in the background while the user
>   moves on to another step